# SDSS. Google Sky and DeCaLs

Tags: amateur-observing, positional-astronomy, observational-astronomy, deep-sky-observing

(1) Please go through following image
[Possible Super Red Giant?](http://skyserver.sdss.org/dr12/en/tools/chart/navi.aspx?ra=126.61547&dec=27.89242)
However sdss shows it as galaxy! Am I missing something.

(2) [Google Sky shows object in latitude and logitude format like this.](http://www.google.co.in/sky/#latitude=69.82067508546967&longitude=-36.44439697265625&zoom=10&Spitzer=0.00&ChandraXO=0.00&Galex=0.00&IRAS=3.00&WMAP=0.00&Cassini=0.00&slide=1&mI=-1&oI=-1)
Is there any way to convert those numbers to Right Ascension (ra) and Declination (dec) numbers or opposite of that  so that I can spot google sky data on SDSS and SDSS object on Google Sky?

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Incidentally afaics Google is displaying locations in RA and dec, but as your question is so unclear I am not sure I am looking at the same numbers as you.

Comment: I dont know how the question is unclear, for first part I am clearly asking that the marked object on SDSS shows as galaxy while it appears to be a huge red giant. 

For second part If you visit first link from SDSS you can clearly see ra and dec values in the address bar however with  google sky link that is not the case. It shows latitude=69.82067508546967 & longitude=-36.44439697265625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sloan Digital Sky Survey has saturation limits at around 13th or 14th magnitude. You are looking at $\phi$ 1 Cancri, which is a 6th magnitude star. It is hardly surprising that SDSS fails to morphologically classify it correctly.

No idea what your second question is about. You have given a link which has a latitude and longitude in the url. Longitude and latitude are not valid ways of expressing the coordinates of a celestial object. When I open this link, I see an image of your star and in the bottom left of the screen there is a display which gives the RA and Dec of where the cursor is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer for first part. For the second part I see on left hand side of the screen 9h 34m 28s and 69 degrees  50" 5.6'
How to convert it to ra and dec values?

Comment: @user3137471 What?? That is the RA and Dec. Are you asking the basic question how do I convert RA, Dec in hms,dms into decimal? There are 24 hours in 360 degrees. 60 (arc)minutes in an hour and 60 (arc)seconds in a minute.

Comment: oh ok, I get it now, I was thinking Right Ascension is some special value. Sorry new to this. There should be setting somewhere in google sky to display in ra,dec directly though :)

Comment: @user3137471 RA and Dec is normally displayed in hms, dms form.